# Multivariable function satisfying $f(x,y)=f(tx,ty)$ for every $t,x,y>0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I want to prove that if $f(x,y)$ has continuous partial derivatives then:
$$\forall x,y,t>0\ f(x,y)=f(tx,ty)\iff x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0\ \text{for every}\  x,y>0$$

In this $\rightarrow$ direction I tried using chain rule but didn't see exactly how it helps me.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the [Euler's homogeneous function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function). [See also this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html)

Comment: Try taking the $t$ derivative of $f(x,y) = f(tx,ty)$

Comment: @Winther This seems to work, thank you. Do you have any idea for the other direction?

Comment: It works both ways. If $xf_x(x,y) + yf_y(x,y) = 0$ then $xf_x(tx,ty) + yf_y(tx,ty) = 0$ and you know this is by your previous calculation.

Comment: @Winther Im not sure I fully understand

Answer (score 1):

Fix $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the curve
$$\gamma : (0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$$
$$ t \mapsto (tx,ty)$$
And observe that $(f \circ \gamma)’(t) = 0$ for every $t \in (0,\infty)$, then the map $t \mapsto f(tx,ty)$ is constant for every $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 $